# Android : How to redirect on my continue activity page?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

On click smsverification() I want open first my sms page of my device then user back from sms page then i want call my redirectContinuePage(); function but when I am clicking on  button then both activity  SMS and Continue opening together.
Due to which the screen of my device is not opening properly.

I want hold to hold my redirectContinuePage() function till its come from sms page of my device.

```
package com.toe.chittychat31;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class PageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView textView6;
    Button btn_send;
    TextView textView7;
    TextView bottom_tc;
    public String mobile_numbers;
    public static String countrydial_code;
    public static String  ccps;
    public static String portal_url;
    public static String sms_num;
    public static String sms_msg;
    public static String flow;
    public static String bottom_tc1="";
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_acitivity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mobile_numbers = intent.getStringExtra("mobile_numbers");
        countrydial_code = intent.getStringExtra("countrydial_code");
        portal_url = intent.getStringExtra("portal_url");
        sms_num = intent.getStringExtra("sms_num");
        sms_msg = intent.getStringExtra("sms_msg");
        flow = intent.getStringExtra("flow");
        bottom_tc1 = intent.getStringExtra("bottom_tc");
    }

    private void smsverification() {
            Log.i("Send SMS", "");
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address"  , new String (sms_num));
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body"  , sms_msg);
        try {
            

// here getting issue
            startActivity(smsIntent);
            redirectContinuePage();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            dialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            dialog.show();
        }
        }
private void redirectContinuePage(){
Intent intent = new Intent(PageActivity.this, ContinueActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mobile_numbers", mobile_numbers);
            intent.putExtra("countrydial_code", countrydial_code);
            intent.putExtra("portal_url", portal_url);
            intent.putExtra("sms_num", sms_num);
            intent.putExtra("sms_msg", sms_msg);
            intent.putExtra("flow", flow);
            intent.putExtra("bottom_tc", bottom_tc1);
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        smsverification();
    }
}
```